# Creating varying number of parameters in an object by dynamically assigning their name?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

How would I write a procedure that would build this array such that I could choose as many parameter names such as KBP? I wanted?

```
public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {Impact:"A", KBP1:1, KBP2:0, KBP3:0, KBP4:0 },
    {Impact:"B", KBP1:0, KBP2:0, KBP3:0, KBP4:0 },
    {Impact:"C", KBP1:0, KBP2:2, KBP3:3, KBP4:0 },
    {Impact:"D", KBP1:0, KBP2:0, KBP3:0, KBP4:8 },
    {Impact:"E", KBP1:0, KBP2:0, KBP3:0, KBP4:0 }
]);
```

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the purpose of this and why you need to do this in the first place.  I'm expecting some kind of bad design somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
var arrayLength:int = 100;
var kbpsLength:int = 50;
var expensesArray:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 0; i < arrayLength; i ++)
{
    var item:Object = {Impact:"A"};
    for (var j:int = 0; j < kbpsLength; j ++)
    {
        item["KBP" + (j + 1)] = 0;
    }
    expensesArray.push(item);
}
var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(expensesArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of your question. If this isn't what you're looking for, feel free to clarify.

```
var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

(loop conditions?)
{
    var item:Object = {};
    item.Impact = "A";
    item.KBP1 = 0;
    item.KBP2 = 0;
    item.KBP3 = 0;
    item.KBP4 = 0;
    item.KBP5 = 0;
    ...

    expenses.addItem(item)
}
```